# Delete SVG element based on text

Tags: python, svg, lxml

I have a SVG file. I am trying to get rid of some elements that contain specific text :

```
<g style="font-family:'ARIAL'; stroke:none; fill:rgb(127,0,0);" >
<g font-size="53.4132" >
<text id="cv_126" x="168" y="474.78" transform="rotate(330 168 474.78) translate(168 -474.78) scale(1 1) translate(-168 474.78) ">SomeSpecificText</text>
<text id="cv_127" x="336" y="474.78" transform="rotate(330 336 474.78) translate(336 -474.78) scale(1 1) translate(-336 474.78) ">SomeSpecificTextBis</text>
</g>
</g>
```

the above example illustrates what I need to do : I would need to delete the entire block (`<g><g> ... </g></g>`) because it contains `SomeSpecificText` and `SomeSpecificTextBis`. I have to do this for any "block" or "element" that contains either one or the other text.

I want to achieve this using Python and lxml because apparently, this provides the necessary tools but I don't know how to use it. I have this code at the moment :

```
tree = etree.parse(open("myFile.svg"))
```

but then I don't know which method I shall use ? I have seen some speaking about xpath and have tried e.g. `tree.xpath('.//g[contains(text(), "SomeSpecific")])` but it returns an empty list.

**EDIT**

I have tried the following, to try to catch the structure that holds "someSpecificText" (partial match required) but it still returns an empty list for `parents`

```
tree = etree.parse(open("svg/myFile_ezdxf.svg"))
targets = tree.xpath('//g[./g[contains(text(),"SomeText")]]', namespaces = {"svg" : "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"})
for target in targets:
    target.getparent().remove(target)
```

Also here is the header of my svg file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- Generated by SomeCompanySoftware -->
<!-- www.somecompany.com -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN' 
'http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd'>
<svg contentScriptType="text/ecmascript" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" zoomAndPan="magnify" 
contentStyleType="text/css" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" 
width="840" height="593.48" viewBox="0 0 840 593.48" 
version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cvjs="http://www.somecompany.com/" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill-rule="evenodd" >
```

Comment: There's a good chance your xpath attempt doesn't work because svg is usually in a default namespace. Try [Jack's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60044818/317052) and if that doesn't work, add the complete svg start tag (or ideally, a minimal but complete svg so we can duplicate) to your question.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't put the whole svg as it contains many sensitive data and I can't take the time to make it anonymous. I tried the solution but it does not work. I will update my post to state what I tried

Comment: In your edit, you bound the "svg" prefix correctly, but you didn't use it in your xpath. Also, `text` is an element so using `text()` in your contains() won't work. Here's how I'd do it: `targets = tree.xpath('//svg:g[./svg:g[.//svg:text[contains(.,"SomeSpecificText")]]][.//svg:text[contains(.,"SomeSpecificTextBis")]]', namespaces={"svg": "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"})` (the `.//` usually aren't necessary, but I wasn't selecting anything without them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the way to perform the task :

```
tree = etree.parse(open("myFile.svg"))
root = tree.getroot()
targets = ["SomeText", "SomeText2"]
for element in root.iter("*"):
   if (element.text is not None) and any([item in element.text for item in targets]):
      element.getparent().remove(element)
with open('myModifiedFile.svg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(tree))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do it with lxml:

```
targets = tree.xpath('//g[./g[text="SomeSpecificTextBis" or text="SomeSpecificText"]]')
for target in targets:
    target.getparent().remove(target)
print(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True).decode())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Beutiful Soup 4 and Python 3 to accomplish this.
In your example this code will do :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

tree = BeautifulSoup(open('svg.svg').read(),features="lxml")

for item in tree.find_all(): 
    if item.getText().strip() == "SomeSpecificText" or item.getText().strip() == "SomeSpecificText" :
        item.findParent().findParent().decompose()

print(tree)
```

Its a little brittle though, as I don't know your exact logic but you can improve it.